# Problem Utf-8 decoding nodejs - Invalid continuation byte at readContinuationByte

Tags: node.js, json, string, utf-8, decode

I'm developping a nodejs server and i want to convert a csv file to a json file. I succeed this part, but on of my data ( the libelle_etape is not on a good format (utf8), the values are like: 'EII/MEA 5Ã¨me annÃ©e' or 'Geau/STE 4Ã¨me annÃ©e' etc...). So in my function i would like to decode those values to have the right format on my json file.

I have the result that i want when i do :

```
 const result= utf8.decode(str)
```

BUT the problem is : when i want to remplace the old String that i have in my csv file (this one : "EII/MEA 5Ã¨me annÃ©e") by the good one (result = "EII/MEA 5ème année") I have the following error :

***Unhandled rejection Error: Invalid continuation byte
    at readContinuationByte ***

The entire code is :

```
CSVToJSON()
  .fromFile('./infoEtu.csv')
  .then((source) => {
    const oneData = source[0];
    for (let i = 0; i < source.length; i++) {
      for (let j = 0; j < Object.keys(source[i]).length; j++) {
        const columnName = Object.keys(source[i]);
        columnName.forEach((element) => {
          if (element == 'Libelle_etape') {
            const str = source[i]['Libelle_etape'];
            const result = utf8.decode(str);
            console.log(result);     // this line show me the good result
            source[i]['Libelle_etape'] = String(result);  // this line is definitely the problem , i've tried with and withou de String() methods but it's the same error
          }
        });
      }
    }

    const data = JSON.stringify(source);
    FileSystem.writeFileSync('./jsonEtu.json', data);
});
```

Thank you in advance for your help, i'm searching for a long time now and i can find the same problem anywhere.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE :

The problem was because of the accents ! 
By doing that it's working :

```
const result = accents.remove(utf8.decode(str));
source[i]['Libelle_etape'] = result;
```